# How to read a CSV from a string?

Tags: csv, julia

I have some data in a csv format. However they are already a string, since i have got them from an HTTP request.
I would like to use `Data Frames`, in order to view the data.
However i don't know how to parse it, because the CSV package only accepts files, not Strings.

One solution would be to write the content of the String into a file, and then to read it out again. But there has to be a better way!

Comment: pass `IOBuffer(your_string)` as a first argument to `CSV.read`

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński could you please post your comment as an answer? so this question cam be marked as solved! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use IOBuffer(your_string):

```
CSV.read(IOBuffer(your_string), DataFrame)
```

Comment: I got to use this at work calling a julia module from python application.